# PhantomJS and Unicode Block 'Private Use Area'

Tags: unicode, phantomjs

PhantomJS has an issues with unicode private blocks. I didn't found any references about it.
The test is very simple just render this [test page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/private_use_area/utf8test.htm) and you will get the results.
Has anyone a resolution for this?

[image]

Comment: What's the issue? The above is a perfectly valid rendering of the characters in the PUA. What did you expect to see instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Private Use Area is one of the blocks allocated for private use codepoints,  often called “private use characters”, though this is really misleading. The [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#pua1) says: “Private-use characters are code points whose interpretation is not specified by a character encoding standard and whose use and interpretation may be determined by private agreement among cooperating users.”

Thus, a private use codepoint has no meaning unless one is assigned, by an agreement between interested partied. You should not expect it to be rendered in any useful way. Programs typically render them using some generic glyph, or no glyph, or e.g. a box containing the code number.

However, fonts may have glyphs representing characters (typically, characters not yet encoded in Unicode). This is completely font-dependent, though the idea is that such allocating reflects some private agreement on the use of private use code points.